# sscanf to uint8 not working in vxWorks platform

Tags: c++, vxworks

I have this code working perfectly in my Windows Visual Studio platform using whatever the latest and greatest compilers are.

```
void ConvertStringToMacAddress(std::string mac_addr, uint8_t mac[]) {
    // sscanf_s in windows
    sscanf(mac_addr.c_str(),
        "%02hhu:%02hhu:%02hhu:%02hhu:%02hhu:%02hhu",
        &mac[0],
        &mac[1],
        &mac[2],
        &mac[3],
        &mac[4],
        &mac[5]
    );
    printf("converted  mac is 0x%x 0x%x 0x%x 0x%x 0x%x 0x%x\n",
        mac[0], mac[1], mac[2], mac[3], mac[4], mac[5]);
}
```

However  On vxWorks 6.9 with c++98 this results in an empty byte array. I see code in my codebase for a similar method and they use formatter `%02X` instead of `%02hhu`. This however causes my build in Windows to crash.. so.. Not sure what is wrong or what to do.

Comment: `%hhu` requires C++11, so it won't work in C++98.  Use `%hu` instead to read the values into an `uint16_t` array first, and then copy the values into your `uint8_t` array.  As for `%X`, without a size modifier specified, it requires `unsigned int*` not `uint8_t*`.

Comment: `%hu` did not work, had to use `%hx`

Comment: Good point, I forgot that MAC address strings are formatted in hex.